# need to use proxy with mvn command

Tags: java, powershell, shell, maven

I need to run this command on powershell
`mvn clean test "-DSUITE_NAME=$SUITE`
but with proxies, i try this
`mvn clean test "-DSUITE_NAME=$SUITE -X -DproxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=XXXX -Dhttp.proxyPort=XXXX -Dhttps.proxyHost=XXXX-Dhttps.proxyPort=XXXX"`
the proxies are right (XXXX is because i dont want to show them)
but the same error came out:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJqLk.png)
need help,
Thanks

trying to run mvn command to start building my proyect, but it cant reach connection with maven.

Comment: Configuring a proxy (https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html), `.m2/settings.xml)`

Comment: Is your Proxy intended for Maven commands or for the Java program being tested?

Comment: Why the quotes?

Comment: already configured the proxy in maven, nothing change.
the proxy is for maven commands, it tries to download artifacts from maven central
The quotes are because powershell read the "." as a different command